# Diagnose and resolve Outlook add-ins conflicts

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have several students working independently on Outlook add-in thesis projects, and we have hit a snag. One student's add-in doesn't seem to play nice with another student's add-in when both are running on the my computer during evaluation and grading.

When both add-ins are enabled, one add-in displays the `this add-in could not be started. close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "restart" to try again.` message and doesn't work but the other one works fine. I am expected by both students to use their add-ins in my daily workflow but due to this conflict I can't. Part of the project rules are that students are not allowed to share add-in code between each other.

I am suspecting it is mail item event trigger/event handler related as both add-ins run when drafting emails. One add-in is a VSTO/COM and the other (failing to load one) is the Office.JS WebAdd-in approach.

Any tricks or tips that I can pass on to them on how to figure out and fix conflicts between Outlook add-ins when they can't tinker with the other add-in?

Comment: I cannot imagine how the two kinds of addins might interfere with each other. It is hard to figure out from one kind of addin to query if another kind of addin is installed (possible, but hard). Does JS addin start working immediately after you disable the COM/VSTO addin from File | Options | COM addins?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko yes as soon as the COM/VSTO addin is disabled via COM addins page then the JS addin works straight away, when it's reenabled then the JS addin stops working on next action.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the addin does. If you suspect it is some kind of an addin event handler, try to comment it out as a test.